# If a value is stored in database I can echo it, but if no value is stored how can I omit the entire tag?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
echo "<a href=\"{$row['link']}\" class=\"button\">Website link</a>";
```

This will display an an anchor tag with a class of "button" and the href value will be whatever is in the database. If I don't have a link stored in the database, I want nothing to appear in the rendered html, but with this example the button will still show up, it just won't have an href value.

I've tried doing this:

```
echo "{$row['link']}";
```

And in the database, the 'link' value would be:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Website link</a>
```

My issue with this is that I don't like storing and pulling html code from the database. Also, if I leave the link value empty in the database, part of the button is still visible because of the "button" class.

Comment: with a conditional statement, too many ways to do this. You'll also need to post your db schema.

Comment: the question is both too broad and unclear. I asked for you to post the db schema for this. Either you don't know how, or have left the question. In any case, you've been given answers to see when you do get back. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm not sure how to sorry. But what @NathanDawson posted solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a very simple conditional.

You have a column in your table for the link so regardless of whether it has a value or not, it will be in the array.

Add an if statement to check it.

```
if ( $row['link'] ) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$row['link']}\" class=\"button\">Website link</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test the data using [isset](http://php.net/isset)()

> PHP : isset() function. The isset () function is used to check whether
>   a variable is set or not. If a variable is already unset with unset()
>   function, it will no longer be set. The isset() function return false
>   if testing variable contains a NULL

```
if (isset($row['link'])){
    echo "<a href=\"{$row['link']}\" class=\"button\">Website link</a>";
}
```

When ever you use a conditional on a var that might be empty always use isset() because if you don't you will get a PHP notice error

If you stored the value in your DB with a NULL then you don't need isset() you can use !empty()

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist. Will also return TRUE on NULL.

```
if (!empty($row['link'])){
    echo "<a href=\"{$row['link']}\" class=\"button\">Website link</a>";
}
```

Comment: `isset()` will fail even on a NULL value in db.

Comment: The array is the result of a database query. The field will still form part of the array so you can't check it with `isset()`. It's always going to be true.

Comment: Use !EMPTY() for test both null and empty. ISSET() returns true on empty variable

Answer (score 0):

try to use the mysqli_num_rows, if result return = 0{ //
} else show the button tag with link